# Blender 2.8 and Google Earth Studio (GES) 3D camera integration/import

Tags: camera

I read lots of threads about Blender 2.8 and GES camera integration and coordinate system issues, however I can not find anything useful in terms simple workflow. Is there a way to import 3D camera information from GES to Blender 2.8?
There is a short tutorial on YT, but it is not much of a help.

I use both software for personal education, but am willing to invest some $ into add-ons/plugins which would integrate two solutions.

Thank you.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this problem a few seconds ago for myself after I found AE2Blend:

https://blendermarket.com/products/ae2blend
($10)

After installing the add-on in blender, I ran the script from Google Earth Studio inside AE and then literally copied and pasted the keyframes into Blender.  Couldn't be easier.

Only issue I'm facing right now is that I animated the Camera Target in GES and that effs up your camera in AE, so I'm currently looking for a solution for this before I have to reanimate.

Good luck!

Gonzalo